Terraform AWS Plugin not Downloading
Trying to get Terraform to download the AWS plugins, but when running terraform init I just get the below
Initializing the backend...
Initializing provider plugins...

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

No indication that provider plugin has been installed. I've tried this on both Windows 11 and Ubuntu Linux using VSCode
Ran terraform init with this in main.tf file.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

Running terraform provider shows nothing installed. Not seeing any hidden .terraform config file either in current working directory.
UPDATE
Ran TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform init
2024-12-17T14:43:54.616-0600 [INFO]  Terraform version: 1.10.1
2024-12-17T14:43:54.616-0600 [DEBUG] using github.com/hashicorp/go-tfe v1.70.0
2024-12-17T14:43:54.616-0600 [DEBUG] using github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2 v2.23.0
2024-12-17T14:43:54.616-0600 [DEBUG] using github.com/hashicorp/terraform-svchost v0.1.1
2024-12-17T14:43:54.616-0600 [DEBUG] using github.com/zclconf/go-cty v1.15.1-0.20241111215639-63279be090d7
2024-12-17T14:43:54.616-0600 [INFO]  Go runtime version: go1.23.3
2024-12-17T14:43:54.616-0600 [INFO]  CLI args: []string{"terraform", "init"}
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /home/cody/.terraformrc
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory terraform.d/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /home/cody/.terraform.d/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /home/cody/.local/share/terraform/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/share/ubuntu/terraform/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/share/gnome/terraform/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /home/cody/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/terraform/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/terraform/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/local/share/terraform/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/share/terraform/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /var/lib/snapd/desktop/terraform/plugins
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"init"}
Initializing the backend...
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2024-12-17T14:43:54.617-0600 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/usr/local/bin"
Initializing provider plugins...


You are certain terraform init is executed in the correct directory?

Yes, certain. From VScode terminal running in a directory named "Code Projects" where main.tf is stored.

From that same directory, try running the following command to see if one is already installed.  Alternatively, you can delete the .terraform directory and run init again.   Here is the command to check: ls -al .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/

@Cargo23 This is the output
cody@athena:~/Documents/Code Projects$ ls -al .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/ ls: cannot access '.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/': No such file or directory
From what I can tell there's no hidden directories just main.tf.

It seems that Terraform CLI is for some reason looking in a different directory, and so it doesn't find any provider dependencies. One way you could debug that is to run terraform console and type abspath(".") at the console prompt, which should cause Terraform to return the absolute path that it thinks is the current working directory.

@MartinAtkins This turns up no output at all.
`C:\Users\lecd\Code Projects>terraform console

abspath(".")
"C:/Users/lecd/Code Projects`


From what you've shared, it seems that Terraform is expecting to find your .tf files in C:\Users\lecd\Code Projects. Does that directory (not a subdirectory of it) contain the main.tf file you shared in the question?

@MartinAtkins Yes, the main.tf is stored directly in the Code Projects directory. Not in a sub directory.

With the help of Claude, was able to troubleshoot and found that creating an entirely new test directory allowed me to download the AWS plugins finally. Trying to understand why this doesn't work in VScode tho.

The issue looks to be caused by file permissions and file ownership. VScode workspace folder was originally created in Ubuntu Documents folder. Creating a separate folder in Home space fixed the issue
